# how to union all two flat files to get all records from two files?

Tags: sql, unix

I wanted to get all records from two flat files like union all in sql.
by using Unix commands or Unix shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in SQL by using union all.
ill explain how to do this in unix:

consider we have two files test1 and test2 and we wanted to get all records from these two files and store them in to testall file.

test1.txt

```
01 alex 12000
02 jack 30000
03 hari 20000
```

test2.txt

```
04 jecs 2500
05 jeri 4000
06 aris 5000
```

**command:**

```
cat test1.txt test2.txt > testall.txt
```

this command will copy all records from both of files and stores it in to test all.txt file.

```
01 alex 12000
02 jack 30000
03 hari 20000
04 jecs 2500
05 jeri 4000
06 aris 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

### Also there is an option to sort the combined file and save

#### use the below command

`cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | sort > file4.txt`

*If you’re combining lists of items from multiple files and you want them alphabetized in the combined file, you can sort the combined items in the resulting file. To do this, enter the basic cat command we previously showed you followed by the pipe command (|) and the sort command. Then, type the output redirection symbol (>) followed by the name of the file into which you want to copy the combined text. All the lines of text in the result file will be sorted alphabetically.*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).